# Want to build the SMS equivalent of a web server

Tags: sms

I want an SMS service that maps incoming SMS-es to an http request to my server and maps my HTTP response to an SMS reply.  Can someone recommend an SMS gateway that provides reasonable service to North America?

Answer (score 1):

Thre are lots of providers out there that can provide this (see google [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=sms+gateway) or [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=sms+gateway+developer+api)). There are also some guides on the web such as "[How to Choose an SMS Gateway Provider](http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToChooseSMSGateway2.asp)".

A couple of examples that look pretty professional (however i have not used them):

- [Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/)
- [CellTrust](http://www.celltrust.com/products/sms-gateway/celltrust-2waysms-gateway.html)

Comment: I have not used the above two but was going through the procurment process for a provider in the US and had them on my final list (deal fell through though which is why i never ended up using any). I accept the criticism that i haven't used them but of course you are welcome not to accept the answer.