# how to start developing an sms service from a web server?

Tags: iis, sms

i need to develop an sms service from iis web server. Iam new to this and i would appreciate any good tutorials on this.

Comment: poke around in google, when you have a problem, then post it here.. we'll definitely help then.

Comment: Search the web for "SMS API" and you'll find many already exist. You are not going to write your own SMS service unless you're actually working at a telephone company. You will use someone else's service from your application.

Comment: My web app must send the sms. is it possible for the web app to send data to these sms-API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need..

```
1. An SMS gateway - Either free or paid, depending on country/carriers
etc.

2. The Web API(specific to your platform), mostly HTTP,SOAP or REST
based to the SMS gateway.So that messages to/from your application
can be translated by the gateway.
```

Take a look at these related topics..

1. [SMS Gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway#Direct_To_SMSC_Gateway)
2. [Programmatic
   SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269/programmatic-sms)
3. [want to build the SMS
   equivalent of a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009775/want-to-build-the-sms-equivalent-of-a-web-server)
4. [Replying to an SMS sent from a
   modem of SMS service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189702/replying-to-an-sms-sent-from-a-modem-of-sms-service)

Comment: i am thinking of using kannel and compile it using cygwin for running in windows. Will it work fine?